# Using paperclip on a join table : job application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

EDIT : I added the file field, and changed the creation of the jobenrollment in the jobenrollment controller 
EDIT2 : the following code should work

I have an app that does job applications. I have a user model (id, name, email), and a job model (id, title). I want my user to be able to apply to a job. So I created a third model called Jobenrollment (id, user_id, job_id) with "user_id" referencing "id" in "User" and "job_id" referencing "id" in "Job"

I have a login system (made by hand following the Rails tutorial). Hence I have a variable called current_user, for the user currently logged in. My UI is the following so far:
- a user is logged in
- they open the show page for a job, see all the info about the job, and can click an apply button via this form (lives in a partial, in the job views folder, that I render):

```
<%= form_for(current_user.jobenrollments.build(job_id: @job.id), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :job_id %>
      <%= f.file_field :resume %>
  <%= f.submit "Apply", :class => "btn btn-large btn-success" %>

<% end %>
```

The user model is the following (user.rb) :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :jobenrollments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :jobs, :through => :jobenrollments


def unapply!(job)
    jobenrollments.find_by_job_id(job.id).destroy
end
```

job.rb

```
has_many :jobenrollments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, :through => :jobenrollments
```

jobenrollments_controller.rb

```
def create
   @job = Job.find(params[:jobenrollment][:job_id])
   current_user.jobenrollments.create!(params[:jobenrollment])
   redirect_to @job
end

def destroy
    @job = Jobenrollment.find(params[:id]).job
    current_user.unapply!(@job)
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

It all works so far. Now I want to augment it, and add file upload upon registration using Paperclip. I have problems with how to incorporate the file field in the form I have..

I ran :

```
rails generate paperclip jobenrollment resume
```

After adding Paperclip to jobenrollments, my jobenrollment model becomes the following :

```
 class Jobenrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :job
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :job_id

   #resume attachment using Paperclip, cf doc in Github readme
   has_attached_file :resume, url: "/resumes/:id/:basename.:extension",
                           path: ":rails_root/public/resumes/:id/:basename.:extension"

    #validates_attachment_presence :resume
```

end

```
== Schema Information
# Table name: jobenrollments
    id                  :integer         not null, primary key
    user_id             :integer
    job_id              :integer
    created_at          :datetime        not null
    updated_at          :datetime        not null
    resume_file_name    :string(255)
    resume_content_type :string(255)
    resume_file_size    :integer
    resume_updated_at   :datetime
```

If anyone comfortable with Paperclip could help me figure this funky thing out, that'd     be awesome. Thaaanks :)

Also let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file_field method is used to add a file upload input to your form. Be sure to make the form multipart.